# Mystery problem with refresh token in react native

Tags: c#, reactjs, react-native, fetch, refresh-token

**Background:** I have a react native app which talks to a .NET framework backend (Web API) using Microsoft token based authentication. The token expires in 30 minutes and then when the next call is made the server responds with 401 and then refresh token API is being called and then the new refresh token is created and app uses this. While we are waiting for refresh token the other calls are queued up on the client and once the token has arrived they are called with new token.

**Problem (mystery):** The problem is that sometimes the status from the server is 0. We have tried to find out why, but with no luck. The pattern we are also seeing is that when the calls for refresh token so the backend deletes the old token and generates a new one. But when the app calls new apis it still uses the same old token and not the new one. This doesn't happen always. Could it be that the qued up calls are not being qued?? And something is wrong there?

**Tools:** We are using four dedicated servers running IIS 10. We have a load balancer to balance the load. On front-end we are using React native 0.64.2. We are using react-native-ssl-pinning to make the calls.

**The Code:** So here is the code

```
async request(route: string,
    action: string,
    params: any = null,
    isJson: boolean = true,
  ) {
    var options = await this.handleOption(action, params, isJson)

    route = Config.API_BASE_URI + route
    
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      try {
        var response = await fetchSSLPinning(route, options)
        return resolve(response)
      } catch (e) {
        // // console.log(e)
        var originalRequest = {
          route,
          options,
        }
        var p = this.handleError(e, originalRequest)
        return resolve(p)
      }
    })
    },
```

Code to handle error

```
  async handleError(error: any, originalRequest: any): Promise<any> {
    const errorResponse = error

    if (this.isTokenExpiredError(errorResponse)) {
      return this.resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error, originalRequest)
    }
    this.dispatchError(true, errorResponse.status)
    return Promise.reject(error)
    },
```

Code to get new refresh token

```
  async resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error: any, originalRequest: any) {
    try {
      
      const resetToken = await TokenStorage.getToken() 
      if (!resetToken) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }

     
      const retryOriginalRequest = new Promise(resolve => {
        this.addSubscriber((accessToken: string) => {
          var options = {
            ...originalRequest.options,
            headers: {
              ...originalRequest.options.headers,
              authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            },
          }
         
          resolve(fetchSSLPinning(originalRequest.route, options))
        })
      })
      if (!this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken) {
        this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = true
        const refreshToken = await TokenStorage.getRefreshToken()
        const userName = await TokenStorage.getUsername()

        const response = await AuthenticationService.refreshToken(
          refreshToken,
          userName,
        )

        if (!response) {
         
          this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
          this.dispatchError(true, '404')
          return Promise.reject(error)
        }
        
        await TokenStorage.storeTokenInfo(
          response.access_token,
          response.refresh_token,
          response.userName,
        ) // save the newly refreshed token for other requests to use

        const newToken = response.access_token
        this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
        this.onAccessTokenFetched(newToken)
      }
      return retryOriginalRequest
    } catch (err) {
      
      this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
      this.dispatchError(true, err.status)
      return Promise.reject(err)
    }
  },
```

Code to run all in subscriber

```
onAccessTokenFetched(accessToken: string) {
    // When the refresh is successful, we start retrying the requests one by one and empty the queue
    this.subscribers.forEach((callback: any) => {
      callback(accessToken)
    })
    this.subscribers = []
  },
```

I do understand that it is hard to come up with a solution but putting it out there as we have been stuck with this for very loog.

Comment: Same issue, did you found anything ? thanks

Comment: You may have an error in the order of subscribing to the token change event and calling the token change event. You call `this.onAccessTokenFetched(newToken)` before `this.addSubscriber((accessToken: string)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition (sometimes the sequence of command go as intended, sometimes not, meaning - there are some commands that are not fully executed before others begin)

After a very short scan of your code, I think I've got something

The function `fetchSSLPinning` is an `async` function (thanks to the below code sample)

```
 var response = await fetchSSLPinning(route, options)
```

However, when resolved from another function (within a promise), it's used like this:

```
resolve(fetchSSLPinning(originalRequest.route, options))
```

Let's break it down:

```
const result = fetchSSLPinning(originalRequest.route, options)
resolve(result)
```

It's easy to see that `result` is a `Promise`, which is not a very good way to resolve a promise. If you intended to make a sequence of promises, using the `await` keyword is preferred (more readable and maintainable as a function of time)

My guess is that you wanted to wait for the result, using:

```
const result = await fetchSSLPinning(originalRequest.route, options)
resolve(result)
```

Or

```
fetchSSLPinning(originalRequest.route, options).then(resolve)
```

That's may be the use case (and probably - you've got some more of these in your code)

And, yeah - if you are using `async` / `await` keywords in your project, try to align the rest of it, in order to maintain consistency

Hope this information helps